# Python importing nightmare

Tags: python, import

I'm having the hardest time trying to import a few things. I have an addon that has multiple files all under one folder with an `__init__.py` in the base. I'm performing all of these imports from this `__init__.py`. The addon folder resides in my addon folder as `scripts/addons/RLD_Toolkit`

My directory hierarchy looks like this
[image: Directory Hierarchy]

The part of the script where it errors

```
def register():
    #These imports do not work
    from . import rld_panel
    import rld_panel

    #This import does work
    import RLD_Toolkit.rld_panel
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Import Error: cannot import name `rld_panel`
```

Why won't it perform the relative imports (or even the straight up import) from my `__init__.py`?

Edit:
Here's a printout of my `globals()` variables and `sys.path`
[image: globals and path]

Comment: My guess: Blender screws up the pythonpath. Print it and see if it makes sense.

Comment: @user277143 Updated post with printout of globals and sys.path

Comment: As you can see, the folder you are in isn't in the import path. As addons is in the python path, saying import RLD_Toolkit.rld_panel imports from the module (that is the whole folder with your __init__.py) the file rld_panel.py. I would advise you to add the current  folder into the path.

Comment: I'm confused?  You're talking about `__path__` right? That's the folder with all my stuff in it.

Comment: Nope. __path__ is the path of the file. When you try to import things, python looks in sys.path, which doesn't contain the folder.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, especially #2: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33603/importing-python-modules-and-text-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, you will have to add the line:

```
sys.path.append(__path__)
```

before importing anything. This will add the current folder into the path Python looks in for imports. Then you can import files  with:

```
import foo
```

instead of:

```
from bar import foo
```

.

Comment: This fixes it. Can you provide any insight as to why this won't work for me yet I have two other addons that perform normal relative imports and it works? Python + Blender is kind of a mystery to me sometimes so some speculation on the inner workings would be helpful to know.

Comment: No living being can hope to understand what happens inside Blender. Turn around, mortal. Your quest is hopeless.

Comment: I need to publish an update to this with code samples, through browsing the Blender Python bindings and trial and error, I've kind of come up with a home brew relative import system that even supports reloading (as long as your code is written in a specific way that doesn't reuse globals and unregisters everything properly).

Comment: This doesn't work with currently Blender / Python. It doesn't recognize `__path__` anymore.