# How to Import Another Python script using Python Script

Tags: python, scripting, import

If I wan't to import another python script(Test_script_1) and also run it through my python script(Test_Script_2)

1. Can this be done through *init*.py script ?
2. Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51044/how-to-import-a-blender-python-script-in-another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've just done, it seems to work.

My paths are:

scripts path -

> C:\Users\Drew\Documents\Development\bfd-graphics\Blender Scripts

mainscript path -

> C:\Users\Drew\Documents\Development\bfd-graphics\Blender Scripts\main.py

blender file path -

> C:\Users\Drew\Documents\Development\graphics\3D
> Assets\Prototype\Blender Projects\Templates\Builder.blend

I wanted to be able to import scripts from a completely different but *known* relative directory. So here is how I tackled it:

```
import bpy, sys
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(bpy.data.filepath)
sys.path.append(str(path.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent) + "\\Blender Scripts")

import test_import

test_import.print_a_message()
```

The number of parents determines where in the directory structure I am, and then I add the rest of the path as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course this can be done. If you have an add-on with its folder and `__init__.py` inside it, if you have other files like `file.py` in the same folder you just import stuff from it like this:

```
from .file import Some_stuff
```

Just open `[Blender's installation folder]\[version]\scripts\addons\` and see how it's done with any of the add-ons in the folders there.