# How to solve the -- Module named mymodule not found -- once and for all?

Tags: python

What do I need to do in order to `import whatEverModul` blender script?

My current understanding is, that I need to repeat some black magic (adding extra codelines) to each new script as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51045/99884) or mangling with Settings>File Paths>Scripts for each new blender version. And: *Adding `__init__.py` does not help*

Comment: That is 'whatEverModul'? Is that something made by you, there is it located?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like:

```
myAddon
├── __init__.py
├── useful_utilts.py
└── app
    └── folder
        └── some_file.py
```

And you want to use a class `some_class` from *some_file.py* and function `some_function` from *useful_utilts.py*, you can do so:

```
from . import useful_utilts
from .app.folder import some_file
```

Then use like this:

```
bpy.utils.register_class(some_file.some_class)
useful_utilts.some_function()
```