# Can i open another script from a script in the same blender file?

Tags: python, text-editor

I want to open + read another script from myScript in the same Blender file.

e.g. i have a csv (in text editor) and want to read that from a script.

because of the comments it tried now this:

MyScript:

```
import MyData


print(MyData.getData())
```

MyData:

```
def getData():

    return [
    1,2,3,4,5
    ]


print ("from mydata:", getData())
```

i got error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyData'

Comment: Well, accessing a text data block is easy: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Text.html but executing it when it’s not the same language would be tricky. I do not remember what CSV is.To execute more Python with Python, just use the built-in exec(“code string”) function.

Comment: @MartyFouts *makes Walden Media beaver “oh yeah! There’s a lot more than hope!” sounds* Oh yeah, you can definitely read that within blender! However, that doesn’t actually sound like a script, but rather just a data file. Is there some other aspect that makes it executable?

Comment: @MartyFouts: yes, you understood correct. It exists on both, but for testing purpose and quick changing data i would like to read it as text data block, if possible.

Comment: ok, found an answer, which works for me here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33603/importing-python-modules-and-text-files

Answer (score 1):

This worked as a charm for me:

```
text = bpy.data.texts['Text'].as_string()
```

Which exactly does, what i wanted: it reads another script in the same blender as text-file, where "Text" is the name of the script

Comment: `txt = D.texts.get("Text")` assigns the data block to `txt` if present.